# PHP: foreach in multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have a dynamic form for creating chapters and sub-chapters that creates an array:

var_dump($_POST);

```
array{["textfield"] => array {
                       [0] => "title one"
                       [1] => "title two"
                       [2] => "title three"
                       [4] => "title four"
                       }
      ["textarea"] => array {
                       [0] => "title text"
                       [1] => "title summary"
                       [2] => "title description"
                       [4] => "title details"
                       }
      ["hidden"] => array {
                       [0] => "1"
                       [1] => "2"
                       [2] => "3"
                       [4] => "1"
                       }
      }
```

I'm very weak with arrays. Ive read several articles on multidimentional arrays and sorting but havent had any luck or seen any examples closely enough resembling mine for me to understand how I need to adjust this.

I would like to for each:

```
<div class="row<? echo $hidden ?>">
    <h2><? echo $textfield ?></h2>
    <h3><? echo $textarea ?></h3>
</div>
```

that matches key 0 (or corresponding key number) and value through several arrays. Similar to:

```
<div class="row<? echo $_POST['hidden'][0] ?>">
    <h2><? echo $_POST['textfield'][0] ?></h2>
    <h3><? echo $_POST['textarea'][0] ?></h3>
</div>
<div class="row<? echo $_POST['hidden'][1] ?>">
    <h2><? echo $_POST['textfield'][1] ?></h2>
    <h3><? echo $_POST['textarea'][1] ?></h3>
</div>
<div class="row<? echo $_POST['hidden'][2] ?>">
    <h2><? echo $_POST['textfield'][2] ?></h2>
    <h3><? echo $_POST['textarea'][2] ?></h3>
</div>
<div class="row<? echo $_POST['hidden'][3] ?>">
    <h2><? echo $_POST['textfield'][3] ?></h2>
    <h3><? echo $_POST['textarea'][3] ?></h3>
</div>
```

This form could dynamically be created hundreds deep and I've only been able to print the entire array or all $values for each $key.  Ive not had any success matching through various arrays.

I hope you follow.  If you have any suggestions, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 3):

In a template:

```
<? for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['textfield']); $i++): ?>
<div class="row<? echo $_POST['hidden'][$i] ?>">
    <h2><? echo $_POST['textfield'][$i] ?></h2>
    <h3><? echo $_POST['textarea'][$i] ?></h3>
</div>
<? endfor; ?>
```

While this will work great (assuming each of the nested arrays are the same length) I think a more appropriate way to build your array would be something like:

```
array{
    [0] => array{
        ["hidden"]    => "1"
        ["textarea"]  => "title text"
        ["textfield"] => "title one"
    }
    [1] => array{
        ["hidden"]    => "2"
        ["textarea"]  => "title summary"
        ["textfield"] => "title two"
    }
}
```

Then your loop looks like:

```
<? foreach ($array as $chapter): ?>
<div class="row<? echo $chapter['hidden'] ?>">
    <h2><? echo $chapter['textfield'] ?></h2>
    <h3><? echo $chapter['textarea'] ?></h3>
</div>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: @MaxSpencer, I was actually editing in something similar. I think changing how the array is built initially makes the most sense.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that each element in `$_POST` has the same length as the others, you can use `count()` to get the length of one of the elements (e.g. `textfield`) and do a `for` loop.

```
$length = count($_POST['textfield']);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
{
    echo $_POST['textfield'][$i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a for loop here instead if you know the array keys:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
    printf('<div class="row%s"><h2>%s</h2><h3>%s</h3></div>%s',$_POST['hidden'][$i],$_POST['textfield'][$i],$_POST['textarea'][$i],PHP_EOL);
}
```

Simples!

Answer (score 0):

is this what you need :

```
    <?php
// $x = %your_array

foreach ($x['hidden'] as $k => $v) {
?>
<div class="row<? echo $x['hidden'][$k] ?>">
    <h2><? echo $x['textfield'][$k]; ?></h2>
    <h3><? echo $x['textarea'][$k]; ?></h3>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Assuming they're all the same length, or you'll get undefinied notices.

Answer (score 0):

If you did want to do a foreach in the template for semantic reasons, you could so some extra work beforehand to swap the dimensions of the array like:

```
$rows = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['textfield']); $i++) {
    $rows[i]['title'] = $_POST['textfield'][$i];
    $rows[i]['text'] = $_POST['textarea'][$i];
    $rows[i]['hidden'] = $_POST['hidden'][$i];
}
```

Then you could do a foreach in your template like so:

```
<?php foreach ($rows as $row) { ?>
    <div class="row<? echo $row['hidden'] ?>">
        <h2><? echo $row['title'] ?></h2>
        <h3><? echo $row['text'] ?></h3>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```